# df shows double the actual size on FreeBSD when run via cron

Tags: cron, freebsd, linux-disk-free

I have written a bash script that collects data from a server
and sends it to a log file that is being monitored by a
splunkforwarder. The server runs FreeBSD and has a ZPool that
is shared via Samba. So of course one of the things I'd like
splunk to keep an eye on is how much space is used on said share.

To keep things readable, I have extracted the lines from my script that achieve this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read disk used avail ; do
        # In reality I pass these values to a function
        # that adds some formatting, but let's keep it
        # simple for the moment
        echo $disk " " $used " " $avail
done < <(df | awk '/datapool\// {print $1, $3, $4}')
```

When I run these lines from the command line I get the correct
numbers (I have compared the output with `zfs list`).
But when I run this script via cron, the numbers I get are all
doubled.

Let's look at the exact output on my machine:

```
# Manually
datapool/myshare   4842023944   24758292883

# Via cron
datapool/myshare   9684047889   49516585766
```

This only happens on FreeBSD. I have another ZFS storage server
that runs on Debian and when I run the exact same script there,
I get correct numbers all of the time.

I have tried running the cron job as different users
(including root), but it's always the same result. I have also
set the PATH environment variable to the same value that I have
when I run this script manually (instead of the shortened
version that cron usually uses).

I have absolutely no clue regarding the cause of this problem
and I really don't know how to debug this problem. Plus I
couldn't find any information on the internet that is even
remotely related to this problem.

I really hope that you can help me out here and ANY hint is
greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `df` uses BLOCKSIZE to determine which units are reported. You may have it set to `k` for yourself (i.e. 1024), but not for root (default: 512).

Comment: You may be up to something :)
I did run the cron job with my own user account (I use /etc/crontab for that) but still got the same results. Does your hint apply in that situation as well?
I will have the chance to test this on Friday, I will get back to you once I have tried :)

Comment: Yes. `cron` probably runs in an environment where BLOCKSIZE is not set, in which case `df` defaults to reporting disk sizes as multiples of 512, which will produce the discrepancy you are seeing.

Comment: Your hint was absolutely spot on. I added BLOCKSIZE=1024 to my crontab and I get the numbers correctly scaled now. Do you mind writing your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`df(1)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=df) uses the environment variable `BLOCKSIZE` to determine which units are used when reporting disk space.

By default, for historical reasons, a block size of 512 is used. It is usual to set this variable within the environment of one's login shell to a more convenient value. For example:

```
setenv  BLOCKSIZE  "K"
```

[cron(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cron) runs with a different environment to the login shell. The symptoms you are seeing are consistent with `BLOCKSIZE` being undefined for `cron`'s environment, and set to a value of `k` or `1024` for the environment of the login shell.

Comment: You can also give df the POSIX-compliant `-k` option to make it use 1024-byte blocks.